# Django multiple SMTP accounts

Tags: django, smtp

Here are the Django simple SMTP backend settings for just 1 email account

```
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
    EMAIL_HOST = "mail.mysmtpserver.somewhere"
    EMAIL_PORT = 587
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = "my@login"
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "mypassword"
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

How is it possible to use 2 or more email accounts on the same server instead of one?

```
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
    EMAIL_HOST = "mail.mysmtpserver.somewhere"
    EMAIL_PORT =587
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = "my@login2"
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "mypassword2"
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

I just need to send different emails based on the subject by different email account.

I checked the Django documentation but there was nothing

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage, get_connection
EMAIL_HOST = "mail.mysmtpserver.somewhere"
EMAIL_PORT =587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "my@login2"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "mypassword2"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
connection = get_connection(
    host=EMAIL_HOST,
    port=EMAIL_PORT,
    username=EMAIL_HOST_USER,
    password=EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD,
    use_tls=EMAIL_USE_TLS,
)

EmailMessage(
            subject=subject,
            body=message,
            from_email=from_email,
            to=[to],
            connection=connection,
        )
```